# Swift: Passing managedObjectContext from AppDelegate to UINavigationController

Tags: swift, core-data, uinavigationcontroller, closures, appdelegate

I have some iOS project (`Project`) with an `@escaping` method in the `AppDelegate` that is used to create the `NSPersistentContainer` for this project. This method is then called within the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method as follows:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer!

    func createProjectContainer(completion: @escaping (NSPersistentContainer) -> ()) {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Project")
        container.loadPersistentStores { (_, error) in
            guard error == nil else { fatalError("Failed to load store: \(error!)") }
            DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(container) }
        }

    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        createProjectContainer { container in
            self.persistentContainer = container
            let storyboard = self.window?.rootViewController?.storyboard
            guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavigationController") as? NavigationController else {
                fatalError("Cannot instantiate root view controller")
            }
            vc.managedObjectContext = container.viewContext
            self.window?.rootViewController = vc
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

The `NavigationController` class is simply a subclass of `UINavigationController`, which embeds a `UIViewController` (`ChildViewController`) and has an `NSManagedObjectContext` variable (`managedObjectContext`), which I want to pass to the first `ChildViewController`:

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController {

    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        guard let vc = self.childViewControllers.first as? ChildViewController else { fatalError("") }
        vc.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext
        print("NavigationController: viewDidLoad")
        print("managedObjectContext ---> \(managedObjectContext)")
    }

}
```

Now the `print("NavigationController: viewDidLoad")` appears to be called twice. On the first call, `managedObjectContext = nil`, on the second call it has been assigned. Does this matter that the app is loading this twice?

It seems to be happening during the `storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavigationController")` which is called **after** the first time that `NavigationController` has been loaded due to the `@escaping` property of the closure. However, if I exclude that line, as just get the reference to the `NavigationController` the `managedObjectContext` appears never to be assigned.

Comment: I suspect this: Instantiation of the root view controller is being performed twice: 1– In code as shown above, 2– through Info.plist’s `UIMainStoryboardFile` key. This is why viewDidLoad is being called twice. Please check your Info.plist setting to confirm.

Comment: @TomE Thanks for the advice. There doesn't appear to be a `UIMainStoryboardFile` key in the **info.plist** file

Comment: If you’re not displaying the raw keys and values Xcode will show this key as “Main storyboard file base name”.

Comment: @TomE Yep - under `Information Property List` there is key called `Main storyboard file base name` with a value set to `Main`. Does that help?